# How to pass data from a form to my controller, and then back to my client-side javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form in my webpage that asks for first and last name. When the user submits this form I would like the data to be passed to a function in my controller, where it is used to find the corresponding user in our Active Directory. I want to then return the matching Email address to a Javascript function, when then displays that information on my page. Is this the "correct" way to go about doing this, and if yes, how would I structure a function in my controller to accept form input, and return data to my client side javascript?

What I have so far in my controller:

```
 public SearchResult[] searchAD(String fname, String lname)
    {
        Func<System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain> domain = System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetCurrentDomain;
        System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://"+domain);
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();
        searcher.SearchRoot = root;
        searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(givenName={0})(sn={1}))", fname, lname);
        SearchResult[] results = new SearchResult['a'];
        searcher.FindAll().CopyTo(results, 0);
        return results;
    }
```

And my form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("searchAD", "AD", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.firstName, "First Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.firstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.firstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.lastName, "Last Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.lastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: You can use Ajax.BeginForm to return data

Comment: Can you post the JavaScript you have so far?

Comment: I don't have any js so far, as I don't know how to pass variables from my controller to my js.

Comment: can you tell what does results returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Store value in TempData and get it on view

```
 public ActionResult searchAD(String fname, String lname)
    {
        Func<System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain> domain = System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetCurrentDomain;
        System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://"+domain);
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();
        searcher.SearchRoot = root;
        searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(givenName={0})(sn={1}))", fname, lname);
        SearchResult[] results = new SearchResult['a'];
        searcher.FindAll().CopyTo(results, 0);
        TempData["Result"]=results;
        return View("ViewName");
    }
```

In View (Jquery)

```
$(function(){
     if ('@TempData["Result"]' != '')
      {
         // call your function here and pass TempData Value
      } 
});
```

Comment: You can also use Ajax.BeginForm

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it will work. I'm getting an error every time I run searcher.FindAll(), but once I fix that, I can try this and mark it as answer if it works.

Comment: `TempData` is for passing data between controller methods (not for passing data to a view). And OP has asked how to do it using javascript.

Comment: We can also get `TempData` Values in the View @StephenMuecke

Comment: That is not what its designed for (use `ViewBag` or `ViewData`). But your answer does not address OP's question, which is about using javascript to return data.

Comment: He said he has to return Data to JavaScript function , the way I have done he'll absolutely get values

Comment: Yes, Ghanshyam is correct. I just want the data passed to a JS function.

Comment: Did you get the value @n.weiss?

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh I'm having an issue with the parameters of my function. I think the values aren't being passed from my form.

Comment: Can you please Elaborate, where you getting the error and if possible show the code

Comment: I don't get an error, but to test, I used the following javascript: console.log('result = @TempData["result"]'); . I changed the controller to set TempData["result"] to fname (one of my parameters) and the javascript just logs "result = "

Comment: fixed this issue. wasn't passing model to view

Answer (score 2):

Above is not perfect solution for your posted issue because tempdata or viewbag are not meant for that.If you need to post data again back from control to view then its always make use of @Ajax.BeginForm

```
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionName", "Controller", new AjaxOptions {  OnComplete = "Sucess" }))
```

in jquery you have to write Success function like below :

```
function Sucess(arg) {
   //arg.data
}
```

in arg.data you will get that object what you are passing from controller.More ever @Html.BeginForm refreshing your whole page not specific content but with With Ajax.begin form you can manage to reload only those content which is under ajax.begin form.